# Future dates in java calendar are giving a strange behaviour

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

I have an application which I create dates that a user can select to an appointment. If a user start to work at 9, and an appointment takes 2 hours, I create dates at 9, 11, 13... until a limit, of course. And then I change the day and start again.
This is the code for doing this:

```
    public List<Agenda> createListOfDates(Calendar initial, Calendar end, 
        int appointmentDuration, int lunchTimeDuration, int lunchTimeStart) {

        List<Agenda> agendaList = new ArrayList<Agenda>();

        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
        agenda.setWorkingHour(initial.getTime());
        agendaList.add(agenda);
        while (true) {

            initial.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, appointmentDuration);
//          Logger.error("" + initial.getTime());

            if (initial.getTime().after(end.getTime())) {
                break;

            } else if (initial.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == lunchTimeStart
                    && initial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY
                    ) {
                initial.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, lunchTimeDuration);
                agenda = new Agenda();
                agenda.setWorkingHour(initial.getTime());
                agendaList.add(agenda);

            } else {
                agenda = new Agenda();
                agenda.setWorkingHour(initial.getTime());
                agendaList.add(agenda);
            }
        }

        for(Agenda agendaX : agendaList){
        Logger.info("" + agendaX.getWorkingHour());

}

        return agendaList;
    }
```

I am working with the "America/Sao_Paulo" timezone to create these dates. I set the variables "initial" and "end" as "America/Sao_Paulo". My system timezone is "GMT", and that is ok, because I want to save these dates in GMT in the database. When I print the dates in last "for", magically it is already converted from "America/Sao_Paulo" to "GMT" and it is printing right. The strange thing is that from a certain date, it changes the time zone. Example of prints:

```
Sat Mar 30 12:00:00 GMT 2019
Sat Mar 30 14:00:00 GMT 2019
Sat Mar 30 16:00:00 GMT 2019
Sat Mar 30 18:00:00 GMT 2019
Mon Apr 01 13:00:00 BST 2019
Mon Apr 01 15:00:00 BST 2019
Mon Apr 01 18:00:00 BST 2019
Mon Apr 01 20:00:00 BST 2019
Mon Apr 01 22:00:00 BST 2019
```

While is in GMT, it is right, but I can't understand this BST. Can it be because it's too much in the future? It always starts on April.

Comment: `BST` = "[British Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system time isn’t GMT, it’s Europe/London (or something similar). In March London time coincides with GMT. Not in April. That’s why.

`getWorkingHour()` returns an instance of `Date` (another poorly designed and long outdated class, but let that be a different story for now). When you append it to the empty string, `Date.toString` is implicitly called and builds the string using your system time zone. During standard time it prints `GMT` as time zone abbreviation. Summer time (DST) begins in London on the last Sunday of March, in this case March 31. So in April `Date.toString` on your JVM uses British Summer Time and its abbreviation, `BST` for printing the time.

The good solution involves two changes:

1. Don’t rely on the JVM’s default time zone. It can be changed at any time from another part of your program or another program running in the same JVM, so is too fragile. Instead give explicit time zone to your date-time operations.
2. Skip the old date-time classes `Calendar` and `Date` and instead use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with and gives much clearer code, not least when it comes to conversions between time zones.

Instead of `Calendar` use `ZonedDateTime`. Depending on the capabilities of your JDBC driver, convert it to either `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` in UTC for saving to the database.

To create a `ZonedDateTime`, one option is to use one of its `of` methods (there are several):

```
    ZonedDateTime initial = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 3, 10, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

This creates a date-time of March 10, 2019 at 09:00 in São Paolo. To add 2 hours to it:

```
    int appointmentDuration = 2;
    ZonedDateTime current = initial.plusHours(appointmentDuration);
    System.out.println(current);
```

Output:

> 2019-03-10T11:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

To convert to an `Instant` for your database:

```
    Instant inst = current.toInstant();
    System.out.println(inst);
```

Output:

> 2019-03-10T14:00:00Z

Instants are time zone neutral, just a point in time, but print in UTC. Some JDBC drivers accept them for UTC times. If yours doesn’t happen to, you will need to give it an `OffsetDateTime` instead. Convert like this:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = current.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output:

> 2019-03-10T14:00Z

Note that I give UTC explicitly rather than relying on the JVM default. So this is *explicitly* in UTC. You notice that the date and time agree with what was printed from the `Instant`.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. I have a doubt now about other thing: why did you wright that Date is "another poorly designed and long outdated class, but let that be a different story for now"?